# Show that the Unit of a Ring is a Group

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Be $R, +, \times$ a Ring with multiplicative identity $1$ and $\#R > 1$.
Then, show that $U(R), \times$ is a Group.

For $U(R), \times$ to be a Group, it has to satisfy four conditions: $U(R)$ must have **closure** under $\times$, $\times$ must be **associative** in $U(R)$, there must be a **neutral element** $\in U(R)$ and each element $\in U(R)$ must have an **inverse** $\in U(R)$.

**associativity**: $\times$ is associative on $U(R)$ because $\times$ is associative on $R$ (it's a Ring).

**neutral element**: It is $1$.

**inverse**: This follows trivially from the definition of $U(R)$.

I don't know how to show **closure**. My textbook says that it is *easily* shown that if $u_1, u_2 \in U(R)$ then $u_1 \times u_2 \in U(R)$ as well. It provides $(u_1 \times u_2)^{-1} = u_2^{-1} \times u_1^{-1}$ as a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint tells you that the product of two units is a unit by providing a concrete inverse. That proves closure.